# Flutter Chopper: how to create a client with multiple services?

Tags: flutter, dart, chopper

At the moment I have these codes:

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';

part 'first_api.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '')
abstract class FirstApi extends ChopperService {

  @Get(path: '/api/v1/mobile/first/')
  Future<Response> getFirsts();

  static FirstApi create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081',
      services: [
        _$FirstApi(),
      ],
      converter: JsonConverter(),
    );

    return _$FirstApi(client);
  }
}
```

and

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';

part 'second_api.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '')
abstract class SecondApi extends ChopperService {

  @Get(path: '/api/v1/mobile/second/')
  Future<Response> getSeconds();

  static SecondApi create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: 'http://10.0.2.2:8081',
      services: [
        _$SecondApi(),
      ],
      converter: JsonConverter(),
    );
    return _$SecondApi(client);
  }
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
FirstApi.getInstance().getFirsts();
SecondApi.getInstance().getSeconds();
```

But I see that it accepts more than one services...

```
services: [
        _$SecondApi(),
      ],
```

Can I lower the amount of code somehow? (If not, I will have 5 more classes just like these...)

If it is possible, how and how to use it?

Edit:

it works like this:

You create services, an example:

File: test_api.dart

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';

part 'test_api.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: '/')
abstract class TestApi extends ChopperService {
  @Get(path: '/modified/{modified}')
  Future<Response> getData(@Path('modified') String modified);

  static TestApi create([ChopperClient? client]) => _$TestApi(client);
}
```

Create the client:

```
class CustomChopperClient {

   static Future<ChopperClient> createChopperClient() {

    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: "http://example.com",
      services: [
        TestApi.create(),
        TestApiTwo.create(),
      ],
      interceptors: [],
      converter: JsonConverter(),
    );

    return client;
  }
}
```

Then you can use the servies like this:

```
    ChopperClient chopperClient = CustomChopperClient.createChopperClient();
    TestApi testApi = chopperClient.getService<TestApi>();
    TestApiTwo testApiTwo = chopperClient.getService<TestApiTwo>();

    // now you can call the getData() that you created in the TestApi service

   testApi.getData();
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this structure?

Comment: I edited the question, added the result I ended up with.  @PurvikRana

Comment: Thanks for adding it. I'll try with it.

Comment: Why are you returning Future from your createChopperClient method?